# Git delete specific folder from repo that doesn't exist anymore on my local project

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

I want to delete a specific folder from my **bitbucket repository** that doesn't exist anymore on my local project folder.

I don't want to commit everything using **git commit -a** because I am still working on something and I don't want to commit it yet also I am ignoring a lot of files/folders and not sure if everything is included into .gitignore ( *I only commit a part of the project due to size* .. ).

So instead of commiting everything for now I just want to **target a specific folder and delete it from my repo**. I am a git beginner .. It must be some easy solution that I don't know and the question could be asked somewhere but couldn't find anything good .. or I am doing something wrong.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: git rm and commit that?

Comment: I can't do that directly because the folder doesn't exist on my local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note 1: You should commit. Your commits will appear only in your local repository, not on bitbucket. You can amend it later before pushing to origin.

Note 2: You probably should learn to use branches on git. They are lightweight and easy to use - it will enable you to switch context of your work easily.

Note 3: You could use git stash, but I feel it may be better to commit your work instead.

So my answer would be:

```
$ git checkout -b my-temporary-branch # create local branch for your work
$ git add -A # add everything, that you worked on
$ git commit -m "AMEND ME LATER"
$ git fetch
$ git checkout -b temporary-master origin/master # I don't know what you committed
                                                 # to your local master already,
                                                 # that's why we're switching
                                                 # to whatever was pushed to 
                                                 # bitbucket already
$ git rm -rf <directory name>
$ git commit -m "Directory removed."
$ git push origin master # publish your changes to bitbucket
$ git checkout my-temporary-branch # back to branch
$ git branch -D temporary-master # remove unnecessary branch
```

Then continue your work; you can fix last commit with

```
$ git commit --amend
```

Note, that you will need to either merge or rebase on top of changes in origin/master before pushing your new work back to master.

Comment: it works, actually I figure out that the problem was with PHPstorm for some reasons is not detecting the changes/deleted files and that's what create the conflict for me .. thx for your answer